# To store pdf files in mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, web-applications

I want to display PDF files in my web application using php and can I store pdf files in mysql database , if so how to store PDF files..?

Comment: Never store files in database , instead upload/store in to the server and save the path in database

Comment: hey there. short answer: no, don't do that, it is an horrible idea. save them on the disk. maybe save some meta information about these files in a database, such as who uploaded them, a title, the path. but don't save the files in the database, please. also your question is too broad, there are a million ways to go about this. as such, I am voting to close it. nothing personal. maybe try to actually do this, and if you have questions, come back here.

Comment: @msonowal and felix Gagnon are saying correct. Never store files in the database. Upload it to some folder and store it's name in database.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion

Comment: 'Never' is perhaps too strong an assertion here, but it *is* a good rule of thumb- and common practice